# Are there any characters that you shouldn't use in a binary file on Debian? (Particularity the EOF char)

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm using binary files to store data in my C++ application on Debian using GCC with C++11. I'm using the "fstream" class to do this.

Are there any characters that might break anything if I use them? For example, will using an EOF character (26 in ASCII) or any other control character cause the fstream buffer to act in a weird way?

Comment: Make sure you open the file in binary mode, and all will be well

Comment: A binary file may contain any sequence of any bytes. That's what makes it binary.

Comment: you can use EOF in binary file

Comment: 26 in ASCII is the `SUB` (substitute) character, which has nothing to do with EOF. It was used as an EOF character by CP/M, and is recognized as terminating text streams by some DOS utilities, but it is in no way an "EOF" character. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: There is no EOF character in Linux. There is also no difference between binary and text file opening modes, though it is a good style to use the binary mode gor binary files anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any byte (incude EOF) in a binary file as long as you are using the correct option.

For C++ iostream, it is `ifstream::binary`.